# How to make a discord bot send a random series of words from a list, but not repetitively?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to specify a program for my discord bot.
Alright so I have this list of `fun_facts` below, and when a user types in the command `!funfact`, I would like my bot to send a random fact from the list but not repetitively.
So each time the command is executed, the used facts are not repeated and sent again.

Here's the code:
Any help to improve it will be appreciated.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    fun_facts = ["Banging your head against a wall for one hour burns 150 calories.",
                 "Snakes can help predict earthquakes.",
                 "7% of American adults believe that chocolate milk comes from brown cows.",
                 "If you lift a kangaroo’s tail off the ground it can’t hop.",
                 "Bananas are curved because they grow towards the sun."]

        if message.content.startswith("!funfact"):
            await message.channel.send(random.choice(fun_facts))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which will use a different fact each time until the list gets exhausted. You also get refreshed list each time your bot restarts.

```py
all_fun_facts = ["Banging your head against a wall for one hour burns 150 calories.",
                 "Snakes can help predict earthquakes.",
                 "7% of American adults believe that chocolate milk comes from brown cows.",
                 "If you lift a kangaroo’s tail off the ground it can’t hop.",
                 "Bananas are curved because they grow towards the sun."]
fun_facts = all_fun_facts.copy()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

        if message.content.startswith("!funfact"):
            try:
                fact = random.choice(fun_facts)
            except IndexError: # the list of fun facts is empty
                fun_facts = all_fun_facts.copy()
                fact = random.choice(fun_facts)
            await message.channel.send(fact)
            fun_facts.remove(fact)
```

If you want the list only to be refreshed when empty, try writing your list to a file:

```py
from fun_facts import all_fun_facts

fun_facts = all_fun_facts.copy()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

        if message.content.startswith("!funfact"):
            try:
                fact = random.choice(fun_facts)
            except IndexError: # the list of fun facts is empty
                fun_facts = all_fun_facts.copy()
                fact = random.choice(fun_facts)
            await message.channel.send(fact)
            fun_facts.remove(fact)
```

Example file storage (`fun_facts.py`)

```py
__all__ = ['all_fun_facts']
all_fun_facts = ["Banging your head against a wall for one hour burns 150 calories.",
                 "Snakes can help predict earthquakes.",
                 "7% of American adults believe that chocolate milk comes from brown cows.",
                 "If you lift a kangaroo’s tail off the ground it can’t hop.",
                 "Bananas are curved because they grow towards the sun."]
```

Comment: Are you missing the remove?

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually really dumb

Comment: Alright so I tried the following, and it seems to give the same result.
Did I miss something?

Comment: Maybe the `@client.event` decorator? I forgot it too and edited it in